# How Logstash read logs from the end every time?

Tags: logstash

Here is my input of conf from logstash:

```
input {
file {
    path => "/usr/local/elk/mos-log/mt.log"
    type => "mos-mt-log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^\["
      negate => true
      what => "next"
      }
    start_position => "end"
}
file {
    path => "/usr/local/elk/mos-log/rpt.log"
    type => "mos-rpt-log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^\["
      negate => true
      what => "next"
    }
  start_position => "end"
}}
```

Every time when I manually add a log into logs,the Logstash always read logs from the head to the end. How do you make sure Logstash read logs from the end?
the field start_position => "end" in conf is not work

Comment: you have type and codec, but i dont see these in the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html i used default setup (with only path defined) and it worked well. Also start_position has "end" as default value, so it shouldnt be necessary

Comment: Check that the inode number of the file isn't changing.